# Проблема с revert в TortoiseGit

Tags: git, tortoise-git

Я сделал мердж своей ветки v1 с v2, далее сделал еще коммиты к v1.
Теперь хочу отменить мердж , сделав revert соответствующего коммита. Но при нажатии на TortoiseGit -> Revert появляется пустое окно. Почему оно пустое?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего, проблема в том, что у merge-коммита не один, а 2 предка, и это сбивает TortoiseGit с толка. Для revert'а merge-коммита требуется указать дополнительный параметр, который пояснит, в сторону какого из предков merge-коммита нужно откатываться:

```
$> git log

...
commit 8f937c683929b08379097828c8a04350b9b8e183
Merge: 8989ee0 7c6b236   <---------------------- предки коммита
Author: Ben James <ben@example.com>
Date:   Wed Aug 17 22:49:41 2011 +0100

Merge branch 'gh-pages'
...

$> git revert 8f937c6 -m 1  # откатываемся в сторону первого предка
```

Возможно, в TortoiseGit не предусмотрен такой сценарий revert'а, что выливается в описанное вами поведение. Попробуйте осуществить revert вручную из консоли.