# Проблема с git revert

Tags: git, git-revert, tortoise-git

Добрый  день!
пытался  сделать git revert к последнему коммиту в ветке мастер, но возникли проблемы. Пользуюсь  я tortoisegit. 
нужный мне коммит  теперь  стал полупрозрачным , а  откат изменений так и не произошел.
Теперь нужный коммит, выделен серым  и в логе tortoisegit помечен как  удален.
Помогите  решить  эту проблему,  заранее всем спасибо!
[image: bitbucket]

Comment: Почитай [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/424595/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D1%81-revert-%D0%B2-tortoisegit), может поможет.